# How to enable auto reconnect of redis connection in Jedis client

Tags: java, jedis

I have an application that stores and reads date in Redis. When Redis goes down and then comes back up, the Jedis connection is not being recreated.

Is there is a way to create a connection retry in Jedis?

Answer (score 5):

One way to overcome the issue is to use a connection pool. I'm using JedisPool. While I cannot find anywhere in the documentation that JedisPool supports automatic reconnect, in my tests, I'm able to continue to use Redis cache after service restarted.

Another option is to use [lettuce client](https://github.com/lettuce-io/lettuce-core/commits/master) which claims to support auto-reconnect.

Answer (score 3):

You may use JedisPool. In case of broken connection JedisPool just invalidates broken connections.

Also you could use [Redisson](https://redisson.org) Redis Java client which has internal ConnectionWatchDog to avoid broken connections. Redisson exposes few settings to control Redis command retry logic: [retryAttempts](https://github.com/redisson/redisson/wiki/2.-Configuration#retryattempts), [retryInterval](https://github.com/redisson/redisson/wiki/2.-Configuration#retryinterval), [timeout](https://github.com/redisson/redisson/wiki/2.-Configuration#timeout)